# Perl code to check my all current running applications on windows

Tags: windows, perl, server-side, perl-module

I am learning perl programming language. I am looking for a code or an idea which checks all my current running applications. This should be on implemented for windows applications.
It can be shell script also but need to track only for windows applications.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I'd recommend using WMI. I've done that in the past, but I have no access anymore to the script I wrote for that about 10 years ago :)

Comment: thanks for this reply STATUS.. I googled on WMI and found that this can be helpful for getting me some windows details.

Comment: why is your question tagged with unix, and not windows. Good luck.

Comment: hi.. its just that i execute perl program sometimes in unix. SO some idea related to unix shell scripting will also work.

Comment: Status, can you please refer me to some book or document to learn on WMI?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of running applications (like the Applications tab in the Task Manager), you want to enumerate the open windows, rather than look at processes.

I was able to make this work with ActivePerl 5.12 (x64). First I installed Win32::GuiTest (`ppm install Win32::GuiTest`).

```
use Win32::GuiTest qw/:FUNC/;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @windowlist = FindWindowLike(undef, undef, undef, undef, 1);

foreach my $whandle (@windowlist)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible($whandle))
    {
        my $wintitle = GetWindowText($whandle);
        my $winclass = GetClassName($whandle);
        unless($wintitle eq "" || ($wintitle eq "Program Manager" && $winclass eq "Progman"))
        {
            print GetWindowText($whandle)."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like **[tasklist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx)** in MS-DOS be useful?

It essentially spits out the "Processes" tab of the Windows Task Manager. You could use `tasklist`'s built-in filtering, or you could pipe the output to a perl script if you really want to use perl.

Comment: i am unable to list the applications using any filter in tasklist. I see processes but not the specific softwares/websites opened